# Get NPE reading null object field when deserializing using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a base class A and 2 child classes B and C extending A. A is an abstract class. And A is a field in another class Something like:

```
@JsonTypeInfo({
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property= "type"
})
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "b"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = C.class, name = "c")
})
public abstract class A {

}

public class B extends A {
    @JsonCreator
    ...
}

public class C extends A {
    @JsonCreator
    ...
}

public class MyClass {
    private A a;
}
```

I want to serialize and deserialize MyClass. While field A in MyClass could be null, and I don't want to skip A during serialization even if it's null. Then when I try to deserialize the json String, I get NPE. I think it is because the Json String don't have a "type" for mapper to look for the subtypes. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually this works fine with Jackson. The NPE is thrown by my own constructor.